# $\operatorname{Span}(T) = \operatorname{Span}(T - \{v\})$

Tags: linear-algebra

Please help : We've been given homework to do problems on vector spaces and I came across one question that I got stuck on.

How do I find the $\operatorname{Span}(T)$ given that $T =\{(1,0,2),(0,-1,1),(1,1,1)\}$? I know the according to the plus/minus theorem $\operatorname{Span}(T) = \operatorname{Span}(T - \{v\})$. I'm not really sure if I should minus one vector from the set of vectors and then find the span of the result I get but then which vector do I choose to subtract from the 3?

Comment: One approach to such problems is to put the vectors into rows of a matrix, then reduce the matrix to row echelon form.  The nonzero rows of the row echelon form of the matrix form a basis (a linearly independent spanning set), and with some additional care you can figure out which of the original rows form a basis (and which can be "eliminated" as linearly dependent on the others).

Answer (score 1):

Notice that if you add the las two vector you get the first vector, and the last two are linearly independent (look at the first component of both), which means that the span is given by...

Can you conclude?
Leave a comment if not.

Comment: ...the set of all linear combinations of the vectors?

Comment: So to answer the question would i have to add every possible subset to see if it results in the 1 remaining vector every time i add 2 of the 3? I cnt seem to understand how exactly to use the formula Span(T) = span(T - {v}).

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** You have three vectors $(1, 0, 2), (0, -1, 1), (1, 1, 1)$.

- Subtract the first vector from the third vector.
- Add the third vector to the second vector.

You should  be left with three vectors, and the second vector should be zero.  Then all linear combinations of the three vectors are given by $\alpha$ times the first vector, plus $\beta$ times the third vector.  The resulting span should be all vectors of the form
$$
(\alpha, \beta, [\text{some expression in terms of } \alpha \text{ and } \beta]).
$$

Comment: could u please give an an example (on how to form this expression) if possible as this is my first time doing this

Comment: @Emmanuel What three vectors do you get when you follow the two steps?

Comment: i get (0,1,-1),(1,0,2) and (0,0,0)

Comment: @Emmanuel Good.  Now any linear combination of them looks like $\alpha(1, 0, 2) + \beta(0, 1, -1)$ (the third vector $(0,0,0)$ won't add anything to the linear combination.)

Comment: So does that mean it is impossile to express these vectors in terms of the span(T) or that the vectors are not a linear combination of each other?

Comment: @Emmanuel I don't understand what you mean.  By "these vectors" do you mean your original vectors, or the new three vectors?  What do you mean "in terms of" the span?

Comment: @Emmanuel Since we just added vectors to other vectors, the span did not change.  So $\newcommand{\span}{\operatorname{span}} \span \{(1,0,2), (0, -1, 1), (1,1,1)\} = \span \{ (1, 0, 2), (0,0,0), (0, 1, -1) \}$.

Comment: Oh now I understand. What I had in mind was that we have to substitute into the Span(T)=Span(T−{v}) formula, that's why I was a bit confused. Ok, Thank You Goos :)

Comment: @Emmanuel You are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is put the vectors in columns and find the reduced row echelon form of the Matrix that you formed.

Example: After you get the rref(A) where columns of A contain all the vectors in the given set. You'll get:

1 0  1

0 1 -1

0 0  0

which you can conclude that the third vector is a redundant vector. First and second vector is enough to span T. By the plus/minus theorem, you can get rid of the third vector and still having the same span. Hope it helps.